# Flash attention argument throwing error while finetuning falcon_7b_instruct

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning, falcon, huggingface-hub

I am exploring the [flash attention](https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention) in my code to fine-tune the falcon-7b-instruct model as it is explained on the [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/perf_infer_gpu_one#flash-attention-2).

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: FalconForCausalLM.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_flash_attention_2'
```

As mentioned on hugging face:

1. I am using data type `float16`
2. Experimenting on falcon model since it can work only on falcon or llama models.

Please let me know if anyone else has also used it, I might be missing something

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade transformers to transformers 4.35.0 using

```
pip install transformers==4.35.0
```